# Spring MVC Controller testing PUT

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, junit5

Trying to test my web tier (spring boot, spring mvc) with junit5 and mockito. All other tests on http methods (get, put, ...) are working fine but the update.
Following the code.

Controller:

```
@PutMapping(value = "{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> putOne(@PathVariable Integer id, @Valid @RequestBody Customer customerToUpdate) {
    Customer updated = customerService.update(id, customerToUpdate);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updated);
}
```

Service:

```
public Customer update(Integer customerId, Customer customerToUpdate) {
    Customer customerFound = customerRepository.findById(customerId).orElseThrow(() -> {
        throw new CustomerControllerAdvice.MyNotFoundException(customerId.toString());
    });

    customerToUpdate.setId(customerFound.getId());

    return customerRepository.save(customerToUpdate);
}
```

Finally the test:

```
static final Customer oneCustomer = Customer.of(3,"john", LocalDate.of(1982, 11, 8));
    
@Test
void putOneTest() throws  Exception {
    when(customerService.update(oneCustomer.getId(), oneCustomer)).thenReturn(oneCustomer);

    mockMvc.perform(put(CUSTOMER_URL + oneCustomer.getId())
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oneCustomer)))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(oneCustomer.getName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.birthDate").value(oneCustomer.getBirthDate().toString()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.name"
```

update(...) method in CustomerService return just null. Can't understand way. Please advice.

Comment: When your MockMvc test fails, Spring will print extensive information on the console, including the contents of the response body. Inspect it.

Comment: the response body is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```java
when(customerService.update(oneCustomer.getId(), oneCustomer)).thenReturn(oneCustomer);
```

You should change it to

```java
when(customerService.update(eq(oneCustomer.getId()), any())).thenReturn(oneCustomer);
```

Because your put request body is a `JSON`, not a real `Customer`, the `when...thenReturn` statement didn't work well as you expected. The mocked `customerService` returns a null by default. This is why you got a empty response. So you must to correct the argument matcher to make it.